# Django model proxy in diffrent package

Tags: python, django, proxy

I want to use one model for global scope for app. In future, probably models will be changed. I created backend.py file in root directory of project with model wrapper (I think it's the best solution as I can change declaration of models in one place, and using global model is more transparent than using imports from app).

```
from project.backend import models as backend_models

class Game(backend_models.Game):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

But when I make any relation to model I get following error:

```
screens.screen: 'game' has a relation with model <class 'energy.backend.Game'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

If I import **project.package.Game,** not **backend.Game** everything works fine. Of course I have  project.backend in installed apps. Only I don't know how to point django that class in backend is installed, and loaded model (from other app).

**EDIT**
I solved it by in backend.py:

```
Game = em_models.Game
```

But there must be same solution with extending model in non-models package.